# Error de arranque de WebLogic 12c

Tags: weblogic

Espero alguien me ayude a solucionar mi problema; estaba corriendo una aplicación en **WebLogic** (En una maquina virtual de Oracle Linux), paso un tiempo donde no realicé ninguna acción en la máquina y se suspendió (Máquina Virtual) volví a acceder y actualice el portal donde esta corriendo el servidor WebLogic ya que decía "No se puede acceder a este sitio" tras varios intentos fallidos, lo que hice fue detener el servidor weblogic para volver a iniciarlo de nuevo pero resulta  que ya no pude arrancarlo, entonces cerré todas las tareas y reinicie la Máquina Virtual aun así no logre arrancar el servidor con el fichero "startWebLogic.sh".

El error que arroja en pantalla es la siguiente:

```
JAVA Memory arguments: -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000
.
CLASSPATH=/u01/app/oracle/jdk1.8.0_202/lib/tools.jar:/u01/app/oracle/product/fmw_12.2.1.3.0/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar:/u01/app/oracle/product/fmw_12.2.1.3.0/wlserver/../oracle_common/modules/thirdparty/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar:/u01/app/oracle/product/fmw_12.2.1.3.0/wlserver/modules/features/oracle.wls.common.nodemanager.jar::/u01/app/oracle/product/fmw_12.2.1.3.0/wlserver/common/derby/lib/derbynet.jar:/u01/app/oracle/product/fmw_12.2.1.3.0/wlserver/common/derby/lib/derbyclient.jar:/u01/app/oracle/product/fmw_12.2.1.3.0/wlserver/common/derby/lib/derby.jar
.
PATH=/u01/app/oracle/domains/mydomain/bin:/u01/app/oracle/product/fmw_12.2.1.3.0/wlserver/server/bin:/u01/app/oracle/product/fmw_12.2.1.3.0/wlserver/../oracle_common/modules/thirdparty/org.apache.ant/1.9.8.0.0/apache-ant-1.9.8/bin:/u01/app/oracle/jdk1.8.0_202/jre/bin:/u01/app/oracle/jdk1.8.0_202/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/oracle/.local/bin:/home/oracle/bin
.
***************************************************
*  To start WebLogic Server, use a username and   *
*  password assigned to an admin-level user.  For *
*  server administration, use the WebLogic Server *
*  console at http://hostname:port/console        *
***************************************************
Starting WLS with line:
/u01/app/oracle/jdk1.8.0_202/bin/java -server   -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -cp /u01/app/oracle/product/fmw_12.2.1.3.0/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic-launcher.jar -Dlaunch.use.env.classpath=true -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer -Djava.security.policy=/u01/app/oracle/product/fmw_12.2.1.3.0/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.policy  -Djava.system.class.loader=com.oracle.classloader.weblogic.LaunchClassLoader  -javaagent:/u01/app/oracle/product/fmw_12.2.1.3.0/wlserver/server/lib/debugpatch-agent.jar -da -Dwls.home=/u01/app/oracle/product/fmw_12.2.1.3.0/wlserver/server -Dweblogic.home=/u01/app/oracle/product/fmw_12.2.1.3.0/wlserver/server      weblogic.Server
<14/05/2019 11:15:30 AM CDT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090905> <Disabling the CryptoJ JCE Provider self-integrity check for better startup performance. To enable this check, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification=true.> 
<14/05/2019 11:15:31 AM CDT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090906> <Changing the default Random Number Generator in RSA CryptoJ from ECDRBG128 to HMACDRBG. To disable this change, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true.> 
<14/05/2019 11:15:32 AM CDT> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000377> <Starting WebLogic Server with Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Version 25.202-b08 from Oracle Corporation.> 
<14/05/2019 11:15:32 AM CDT> <Info> <RCM> <BEA-2165021> <"ResourceManagement" is not enabled in this JVM. Enable "ResourceManagement" to use the WebLogic Server "Resource Consumption Management" feature. To enable "ResourceManagement", you must specify the following JVM options in the WebLogic Server instance in which the JVM runs: -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+ResourceManagement.> 
<14/05/2019 11:15:33 AM CDT> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLogic Server 12.2.1.3.0 Thu Aug 17 13:39:49 PDT 2017 1882952> 
<14/05/2019 11:15:36 AM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING.> 
<14/05/2019 11:15:36 AM CDT> <Info> <WorkManager> <BEA-002900> <Initializing self-tuning thread pool.> 
<14/05/2019 11:15:36 AM CDT> <Info> <WorkManager> <BEA-002942> <CMM memory level becomes 0. Setting standby thread pool size to 256.> 
<14/05/2019 11:15:38,398 AM CDT> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170019> <The server log file weblogic.logging.FileStreamHandler instance=1828139200
Current log file=/u01/app/oracle/domains/mydomain/servers/AdminServer/logs/AdminServer.log
Rotation dir=/u01/app/oracle/domains/mydomain/servers/AdminServer/logs
 is opened. All server side log events will be written to this file.> 
<14/05/2019 11:15:38,814 AM CDT> <Error> <EmbeddedLDAP> <BEA-000000> <Error opening the Transaction Log: /u01/app/oracle/domains/mydomain/servers/AdminServer/data/ldap/ldapfiles/EmbeddedLDAP.tran (Permiso denegado)> 
<14/05/2019 11:15:38,890 AM CDT> <Error> <EmbeddedLDAP> <BEA-000000> <Error Instantiating 'dc=mydomain': null> 
<14/05/2019 11:15:38,892 AM CDT> <Critical> <EmbeddedLDAP> <BEA-171522> <An error occurred while initializing the embedded LDAP server. The exception that occurred is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.octetstring.vde.backend.BackendRoot cannot be cast to com.octetstring.vde.backend.standard.BackendStandard. This may indicate a problem with the data files for the embedded LDAP server. If the problem is with the data files, and it cannot be corrected, backups of previous versions of the data files exist in /u01/app/oracle/domains/mydomain/servers/AdminServer/data/ldap/backup.> 
<14/05/2019 11:15:39,058 AM CDT> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000362> <Server failed. Reason: 

There are 1 nested errors:

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.octetstring.vde.backend.BackendRoot cannot be cast to com.octetstring.vde.backend.standard.BackendStandard
    at weblogic.ldap.EmbeddedLDAP.start(EmbeddedLDAP.java:318)
    at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1287)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:333)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:375)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:212)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:235)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:212)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:235)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:212)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:235)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:212)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:235)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1237)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1168)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:670)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)

> 
<14/05/2019 11:15:39,099 AM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FAILED.> 

<14/05/2019 11:15:39,100 AM CDT> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000383> <A critical service failed. The server will shut itself down.> 

<14/05/2019 11:15:39,115 AM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FORCE_SHUTTING_DOWN.> 

Stopping Derby server...
Derby server stopped.

[oracle@was mydomain]$
```

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Comment: esa es toda la trama del error que te arroja??

Comment: puedes poner lo que te arroja al inicio? lo que te arroja cuando ejecutas tu sh

Comment: No,  soló es una parte del trama, en unos instantes lo subo completo.

Comment: Ya actualice, eso es todo lo que arroja al momento de la ejecución...

Comment: Aparentemente los datos LDAP para el servidor WebLogic estan dañados. Pase por la misma situación, en una ocasión lo que te dejo a continuación me funciono [datos LDAP dañados en WebLogic](https://pitss.com/us/2014/07/02/unable-to-start-weblogic-admin-server/) en otra ocasión no! supongo porque era una instalación diferente. La otra "solución" fue volver a hacer la instalación!

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! por tu ayuda lo pondré en practica, excelente día.

Comment: De nada, ojala solucione tu problema, si es así házmelo saber para colocarla como respuesta.

Comment: De nuevo yo @YSCGProJ, seguí todos los pasos pero no funcionó lo intente varias veces pero no dio un resultado favorable.

Comment: Veras @Mario te comenté que en cierta ocasión la información de la liga que puse había resuelto el problema, pero en otra ocasión no lo hizo y ciertamente no se porque, lo que hice fue instalar nuevamente. Desafortunadamente en su momento no encontré otra solución.

Comment: Gracias de todas maneras, seguiré buscando alguna solución por que no quiero instalar de nuevo ya que tengo instalado aplicaciones en los servidores junto a varios clusters  y seria un caos total empezar de cero, gracias por responder.

Comment: De nada, te pido que si encuentras una solución no dudes en colocarla como respuesta. Y te comprendo perfectamente, pero muchas veces créeme que la reinstalación es lo más rápido.